# Show different data based on the active carousel item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation, carousel

I have a horizontal <Animated.ScrollView>, a "carousel" in my React-native app that displays one item at the center of the screen and the edges of previous and next item. I want to show data (lessons) below the ScrollView. **Can someone tell me or point to a resource about how can I know what item the screen is now displaying and then showing data based on that?** Do I need to calculate the current item in the scrollview or pass it as an argument to some function?

My goal:

[image]

Parent component:

```
 return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <View style={styles.thumbnailScrollContainer}>
    <HorizontalContentScroll
      data={LESSONS_DATA}
    />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.dataScrollContainer}>
    <FlatList numColumns={2} data={lessonsByCategory} renderItem={renderLessonItem} />
  </View>
</View> );
```

And here my horizontal Scrollview

```
const HorizontalContentScroll = ({ data}: HorizontalContentProps) => {
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const ITEM_SIZE = width * 0.8;

  const getInterval = (offset: any) => {
    // console.log('offset', offset);
  };

  const scrollableData = (data as Array<ContentCategory>).map(
    (item: ContentCategory, index: number) => {
      const inputRange = [
        (index - 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
        index * ITEM_SIZE,
        (index + 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
      ];
      const translateY = scrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [40, 10, 40],
        // extrapolate: 'clamp',
      });

      return (
        <Card
          size="large"
          style={{
            ...styles.titleCard,
            transform: [{ translateY }],
            width: ITEM_SIZE,
          }}
          key={`${item.category}-${index}`}
        >
          <Text>{item.category}</Text>
        </Card>
      );
    }
  );

  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      horizontal
      onScroll={Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
        {
          useNativeDriver: true,
          listener: (event) => {
            getInterval(event);
          },
        }
      )}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      bounces={false}
      pagingEnabled
      snapToAlignment="center"
      snapToInterval={330}
      decelerationRate={'fast'}
    >
      {scrollableData}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

export default HorizontalContentScroll;
```

I think I have to do something in this map function like pass the current item up to my parent component but how? If I try to call a function that sets the state in the parent I get an error of "Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component."

```
const scrollableData = (data as Array<ContentCategory>).map(
    (item: ContentCategory, index: number) => {
      const inputRange = [
        (index - 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
        index * ITEM_SIZE,
        (index + 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
      ];

      const translateY = scrollX.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [40, 10, 40],
      });

      // filterLessonsInTheParent(item)
      
      return (
        <Card
          size="large"
          style={{
            ...styles.titleCard,
            transform: [{ translateY }],
            width: ITEM_SIZE,
          }}
          key={`${item.category}-${index}`}
        >
          <Text>{item.category}</Text>
        </Card>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it.

I used Animated.Flatlist instead of Animated.Scrollview so that I could get my hands on the `onViewableItemsChanged` prop and then I had to refactor my component to a class component so that `viewabilityConfig` prop would work properly.

I pass the current viewable item to the parent in a useCallback function that updates the local state. I then use that and React Pure Component to avoid re-rendering my `HorizontalContentScroll` which would mess up the animation positions. (I don't know if this is the most optimal way but it works so far).

```
// Parent
const handleViewableChange = useCallback((item: ContentCategory) => {
    setContentsToShow((prevItem) => item.contents);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.thumbnailScrollContainer}>
        <HorizontalContentScroll
          data={LESSONS_DATA}
          onViewableChange={handleViewableChange }
        />
      </View>
      <View>

          <FlatList
            numColumns={2}
            data={contentsToShow}
            renderItem={renderLessonItem}
          />
```

```
// HorizontalContentScroll
class HorizontalContentScroll extends PureComponent<HoriProps, any> {
  viewabilityConfig: { viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: number };
  scrollX: any;
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.handleViewableItemsChanged = this.handleViewableItemsChanged.bind(
      this
    );
    this.viewabilityConfig = { viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50 };
  }

  handleViewableItemsChanged = (info: any) => {
    const currItemInView = info.viewableItems[0].item;
    this.props.onViewableChange(currItemInView);
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
    const ITEM_SIZE = width * 0.8;

    return (
      <Animated.FlatList
        data={data}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        onViewableItemsChanged={this.handleViewableItemsChanged}
        viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        snapToAlignment="center"
        snapToInterval={330}
        decelerationRate={'fast'}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          {
            useNativeDriver: true,
          }
        )}
        renderItem={({
          item,
          index,
        }: {
          item: ContentCategory;
          index: number;
        }) => {
          const inputRange = [
            (index - 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
            index * ITEM_SIZE,
            (index + 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
          ];
          const translateY = scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            // [x, y, x]
            outputRange: [40, 10, 40],
            // extrapolate: 'clamp',
          });
          return (
            <Card
              size="large"
              style={{
                ...styles.titleCard,
                transform: [{ translateY }],
                width: ITEM_SIZE,
              }}
              key={`${item.category}-${index}`}
            >
              <Text style={styles.categoryText}>{item.category}</Text>
            </Card>
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default HorizontalContentScroll;
```